# how to fix the error ERROR [CompactionExecutor:5] CassandraDaemon.java:195

Tags: database, cassandra

I have an error in cassandra database:

> ERROR [CompactionExecutor:5] 2016-03-29 08:14:48,471
>   CassandraDaemon.java:195 - Exception in thread
>   Thread[CompactionExecutor:5,1,main] java.lang.AssertionError:
>   /var/lib/cassandra/data/system_schema/keyspaces-abac5682dea631c5b535b3d6cffd0fb6/ma-85-big-Data.db

What is the reason?

Comment: When I run Cassandra I get this error

Comment: INFO  11:11:04 Harmless error reading saved cache /var/lib/cassandra/saved_caches/KeyCache-d.db
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cache schema version caad3cff-3fc7-30bd-873b-4f6eab12de14 does not match current schema version c89c887a-75eb-30dd-aa88-b77e7d7e22dd
        at org.apache.cassandra.cache.AutoSavingCache.loadSaved(AutoSavingCache.java:198) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
        at org.apache.cassandra.cache.AutoSavingCache$3.call(AutoSavingCache.java:157) [apache-cassandra-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that

```
in_memory_compaction_limit_in_mb
```

is set too low in your setup and your rowsize is greater.

Change the in_memory_compaction_limit_in_mb: 1 to

```
in_memory_compaction_limit_in_mb: 64
```

and this should solve your problem

Also have you tried to
wipe all the data directories, saved_cache, and commitlog and let the node bootstrap again?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to increase in_memory_compaction_limit_in_mb